# How can I create a class that extends Rx.Observable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've already use the latest version of the rx.js typing from Definitely Typed.

And when I try this:

```
class MyObservable extends Rx.Observable<any> { }
```

I got: `A class may only extend another class.`

Why the `Observable` and `Subject` etc, defined as an interface instand of a class in `rx.d.ts`?

And how can I do, if I want create a class that extends Observable or Subject?

P.S. I want this class to handle specific domain logics, so I need create a new class, instead of update Observable's prototype directly.

Thanks!

Comment: There are many types of observables all of which implement the same interface.

Comment: Yes, but no one I can use in typescript. I think the problem was about the `rx.d.ts`. May be I should rewrite it by my self?

Comment: Not terribly familiar with Typescript but doesn't one usually `implement` interfaces with classes, not `extend` them?

Comment: When I try to `implement` the `Observable` interface, it tell me `Class 'MyOb' incorrectly implements interface 'Observable<any>'.
  Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'MyOb'.` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to solve the same problem for [WebRx](http://webrxjs.org/). As you have already found out, extending RxJS's IObservable using a Typescript class is not an option because Observable is being exported as an interface. As I've mentioned in my comment on Steve Fenton's answer, creating a class that implements Rx.IObservable won't get you very far either because the vast majority of the Rx Operators is defined around Rx.Observable interface which is derived from Rx.IObservable. You would pretty much end up with a rewrite of Rx.Observable.

The way I've tackled the problem until there's a better way is to extend the built-in Rx.Observable using [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/WebRxJS/WebRx/blob/master/src/RxJsExtensions.ts) and export the extension via a [custom d.ts](https://github.com/WebRxJS/WebRx/blob/master/src/Interfaces.ts#L896) file:

**RxExtension.ts**

```
var RxObsConstructor = (<any> Rx.Observable);   // this hack is neccessary because the .d.ts for RxJs declares Observable as an interface)

/**
* Creates an read-only observable property with an optional default value from the current (this) observable
* (Note: This is the equivalent to Knockout's ko.computed)
* @param {T} initialValue? Optional initial value, valid until the observable produces a value
*/
RxObsConstructor.prototype.toProperty = function(initialValue?: any, scheduler?: Rx.IScheduler) {
    scheduler = scheduler || Rx.Scheduler.currentThread;

    // initialize accessor function (read-only)
    var accessor: any = (newVal?: any): any => {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            internal.throwError("attempt to write to a read-only observable property");
        }

        if (accessor.sub == null) {
            accessor.sub = accessor._source.connect();
        }

        return accessor.value;
    };

    //////////////////////////////////
    // IUnknown implementation

    accessor.queryInterface = (iid: string) => {
        if (iid === IID.IUnknown ||
            iid === IID.IObservableProperty ||
            iid === IID.IDisposable)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    //////////////////////////////////
    // IDisposable implementation

    accessor.dispose = () => {
        if (accessor.sub) {
            accessor.sub.dispose();
            accessor.sub = null;
        }
    };

    //////////////////////////////////
    // IObservableProperty<T> implementation

    accessor.value = initialValue;

    // setup observables
    accessor.changedSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();
    accessor.changed = accessor.changedSubject
        .publish()
        .refCount();

    accessor.changingSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();
    accessor.changing = accessor.changingSubject
        .publish()
        .refCount();

    accessor.source = this;
    accessor.thrownExceptions = internal.createScheduledSubject<Error>(scheduler, app.defaultExceptionHandler);

    //////////////////////////////////
    // implementation

    var firedInitial = false;

    accessor.sub = this
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(x => {
            // Suppress a non-change between initialValue and the first value
            // from a Subscribe
            if (firedInitial && x === accessor.value) {
                return;
            }

            firedInitial = true;

            accessor.changingSubject.onNext(x);
            accessor.value = x;
            accessor.changedSubject.onNext(x);
        }, x=> accessor.thrownExceptions.onNext(x));

    return accessor;
}
```

**RxExtension.d.ts**

```
declare module Rx {
    export interface Observable<T> extends IObservable<T> {
        toProperty(initialValue?: T): wx.IObservableProperty<T>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This can be used as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying `Observable` in rx.js can't be extended because it is more like a TypeScript `module` than a `class` (i.e. it is a singleton).

```
 var Observable = Rx.Observable = (function () {
     //...
 })();
```

This is why it is modelled as an interface, not a class, in the Definitely Typed definition. To implement an interface, you must supply a structure that is compatible with the interface. Here is an example for `IObservable<T>`.

```
class MyObservable<T> implements Rx.IObservable<T> {
    subscribe(observer: Rx.Observer<T>): Rx.IDisposable;
    subscribe(onNext?: (value: T) => void, onError?: (exception: any) => void, onCompleted?: () => void): Rx.IDisposable;
    subscribe(a?: Rx.IObserver<T> | Function, onError?: (exception: any) => void, onCompleted?: () => void) {
        return null;
    }

    subscribeOnNext(onNext: (value: T) => void, thisArg?: any): Rx.IDisposable {
        return null;
    }

    subscribeOnError(onError: (exception: any) => void, thisArg?: any): Rx.IDisposable {
        return null;
    }

    subscribeOnCompleted(onCompleted: () => void, thisArg?: any): Rx.IDisposable {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will only work in theory Steve. That's because the vast majority of the Rx Operators is defined around Rx.Observable interface (which is derived from Rx.IObservable). Which means you would need to implement a metric ton of methods (basically everything).